# Teradata script is throwing error while executing it through Jenkins

Tags: sql, jenkins, liquibase, cicd, teradata-sql-assistant

```
REPLACE MACRO Macroname
(
col1 TIMESTAMP(0)
)
AS
(  
    DELETE FROM
        tabe1
    WHERE td_colnm = 'Jenkins';
);
```

I am getting  the below error in Jenkins on the script execution.

"Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 17.00.00.03] [Error 3707] [SQLState 42000] Syntax error, expected something like ')' between ';' and the end of the request. [Failed SQL: (3707)" REPLACE MACRO Macroname
(
col1 TIMESTAMP(0)
)
AS
(
DELETE FROM
tabe1
WHERE td_colnm = 'Jenkins']

Can anyone provide the solution please?

Comment: I am not familiar with teradata syntax but reading the error looks like the somehow the last ) is not picked up in the execution stack; can you try with having everything in one line, just for the sake of a test for the moment? try with... ( DELETE FROM tabe1 WHERE td_colnm = 'Jenkins'; );

Comment: Looks like you have delimiter=';' in Liquibase and the text is being treated as two separate requests - the trailing `);` was not included in the request sent to the database. Maybe you need to use a different change type like "Procedure" instead of generic SQL?